# Powershell -> Get-ADComputer error when trying to get Dist.Name from Wkst LoginIDs imported from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am trying to get DNs for WorkStations from a CSV list.

```
$distname = (Get-ADComputer "$($wkst.wkstID)").distinguishedName
```

The above line is causing an error, because `$wkst.wkstID` is not listing `SameAccountNames` individually, but it copies the whole CSV list into the same command.

Could anybody please assist with this error?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$wkst = import-csv XXX.csv

Foreach($wkstID in $wkst){

$distname = (Get-ADComputer "$($wkst.wkstID)").distinguishedName

#Remove-ADObject -Identity $distname

}
```

[image: CSV Screenshot]

[image: Error screenshot]

[CSV opened in Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMIIo.png)

Comment: `Import-Csv` without parameter `-Delimiter` defaults to a comma. Probably your csv file uses a different character to separate the fields.

Comment: Excel data are separated into separate rows. I thought -Delimiter does not impact this data setup?

Comment: Show us the first 3 lines of the real csv as opened in notepad so we can see what the structure looks like. We cannot see that from a screenshot taken from Excel.

Comment: CSV structure in Notepad:

Comment: Also, you need to change `Get-ADComputer "$($wkst.wkstID)")` into `Get-ADComputer $wkstID.wkstID` so you are using the variable name you iterate the collection with. May i suggest you use better variable names to avoid confusion>

Comment: I put the CSV opened in Note picture to the main post.

Comment: Did you see my previous comment about the variable name?

Comment: Your suggestion about the variable change does not work with .distinguishedName. Could you please type out the entire line? 
"$distname = Get-ADComputer $wkstID.wkstID.distinguishedName" receives "Cannot validate argument on parameter "Identity" " error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'd probably write an answer than using comments on this.

In your code, you are creating a variable to iterate a collection of items with `foreach($wkstID in $wkst){..}`, but inside the loop you are taking the **property** from the whole collection with `$wkst.wkstID` instead of taking it from your iteration variable.

That is why I commented to use better names to avoid the confusion you now have when the variable name is the same as the property you are using from it.

Try

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$wkst = Import-Csv -Path 'XXX.csv'

foreach($item in $wkst){
    $distname = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $item.wkstID).DistinguishedName
    # Remove-ADObject -Identity $distname
}
```

The above may throw exceptions when a computer with that name is not found, so perhaps better use something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$wkst = Import-Csv -Path 'XXX.csv'

foreach($item in $wkst){
    $computer = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$($item.wkstID)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($computer) {
        # Remove-ADObject -Identity $computer.DistinguishedName
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$($item.wkstID)' does not exist"
    }
}
```